# Does stripping all symbols from a static library prevent linking?

Tags: c++, c, linker

As far as I know, the linker's job is to match undefined symbols in an object file with symbols defined in a static library. If found, the proper symbol definition is included into the final executable. This is the so-called symbol resolution.

So what happens if all symbols get stripped away from the static library? Does it prevent the linker to resolve symbols correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripping symbols is an operation that's normally meant to remove *debug* information on symbols, not symbols needed for the actual linking process (though it can be used to remove symbols for things that you don't *want* used in the linking process if, for example,  you didn't generate the object file).

It would be a rather bad use of the tool were it to render libraries or object file useless for linking.

Don't get me wrong, you *can* actually do this with, for example, `strip --strip-all`, it's just not a sensible thing to do. For example, consider the files `prog1.c` and `prog2.c`:

```
// prog1.c
int fn(void);
int main(void) { return fn(); }

// prog2.c
int fn(void) { return 42; }
```

Running the following commands on these files:

```
gcc -o prog1.o -c prog1.c
gcc -o prog2.o -c prog2.c
strip --strip-all prog2.o
gcc -o prog prog1.o prog2.o
```

will result in a linker error because it cannot find `fn()` - it's been stripped from `prog2.o`. However, executing the same commands except for the `strip` will work just fine.