# Why strip all symbols from a library?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, debug-symbols

I intermittently find people confused over how to strip debug symbols from libraries: they will mistakenly run `strip libfoo.so.1.0.0` instead of `strip -g libfoo.so.1.0.0`. The latter, i.e. stripping *debug* symbols, is typically what people intend. Doing the former, by stripping *all* symbols, will cause link errors.

**Question: when is it useful to strip all symbols?** I'm having a hard time figuring out what purpose a library with *all symbols* stripped would serve. I mean: if a library cannot be linked to, why is it useful?

I've used the example of a shared library above, but I think this question applies equally between shared and static libraries.

---

Read: [Does stripping all symbols from a static library prevent linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411685/does-stripping-all-symbols-from-a-static-library-prevent-linking)

Comment: Isn't this answered at the other question? The only sensible answer to "why?" would be "because they made a mistake".

Comment: There are options to *keep* certain symbols. So it might be useful to strip all but few specific exceptions.

Comment: @Barmar - I have a tendency to err on the side of _my_ lack of understanding -- so I kind of thought there was some legit reason just not yet addressed at the other question.